# Realtime IE JavaScript evaluator available?

Tags: internet-explorer, jscript, evaluator, browserstack

I was wondering if there's such a thing like an online IE 8 JavaScript parser? Something similar to this [Realtime JavaScript Evaluator](http://www.teria.com/~koseki/memo/javascript/realtime_eval.html), with a console.

Something to help test what works/doesn't work with those older browsers.

I know of tools like [BrowserStack](http://browserstack.com), which let you load a virtual browser, but that's a bit more troublesome than what I'm thinking of as you can't copy and paste stuff from your computer to the virtual computer, along with other small issues.

Comment: If you point your IE to the URL or (questions of ethics aside) a saved copy of the URL's source, IE surely will use JScript to process the code and your input.

Comment: I don't quite follow. I'm asking from a mac point of view, so without a virtual windows I cannot run and test IE code

Comment: I'm sorry to have bothered you, but my crystal ball is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown below, BrowserStack does actually allow you to copy+paste into an IE 8 session.

I've pasted some sample JavaScript into the console window and it also comes with Firebug Lite.

[image]